# How to automatically claim testnet faucet tokens via a programming language script?

Tags: python, solidity, cryptocurrency, metamask, bitcoin-testnet

Is it possible to create such a script that automatically triggers a transaction from my MetaMask account to claim the testnet faucet tokens from the targeted websites.

I am new to programming. All I want is to find such a script that is compatible with the EVM compatible wallets especially METAMASK.

Answer (score 0):

> automatically triggers a transaction from my MetaMask

This is not entirely possible because Metamask will always require your confirmation (click on the Metamask popup) to send a transaction, and this is for security.

Also, if you want to interact with Metamask the script will need to be running in the browser.

The best option for what you are asking would be to send a transaction from a script directly without involving metamask. But in order to claim tokens from a faucet you will need to find a faucet that supports that, so thats where you should start.